# Redirect page when to try debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I assigned a project that is already been exists and can not reach it's developer.

My problem is when I hit the debug button on visual studio, project redirect itself to production URL.

I can see `http://localhost:55291` url for a second but then redirects to `https://test.customer.com` url.

What I've been tried so far;
searched entire project (including app config files in .vs folder) for "https://test.customer.com", there is no result!
set a break point on a first line of Application_Start in `Global.asax.cs`, it's not hit the line!
looked for the prod url in database, no result!

Where should I look for next?

Workaround solution:

I changed the debug port and it worked!

And now I believe the problem is about to my computer but can not be sure.

Comment: Search for just "test" or "test.customer"? Sounds like the app redirects somewhere.

Comment: @Max thanks for quick reply. I already tried what you said, no luck!